# CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I am trying to run Flutter app on iOS Simulator. But it is returning me error:

```
Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
        [33mWARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
        Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

        export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
        [0m

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone Xʀ.
```

It is working perfectly with my Android emulator.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: Yes I did. Please follow this URL:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1036#issuecomment-20675439

Answer (score 0):

I was searching a lot to run the project directly in iOS device or Simulator for my flutter project. Finally, below thing worked!

If you're using Android Studio or VSCode for your flutter projects,
just run the following command in your Android Studio terminal:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

And then just do `flutter clean` & `flutter run`

Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

You can try
1) flutter clean
2) flutter run